# Django model inheritance structure

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django models and need advice on how best to structure my models.
My site has services, each service has multiple plans. each company can have multiple services with one plan for the service. Here is a basic structure i have

```
class BaseService(models.Model):
   some fields

class ServiceA(BaseService):
   some fields/methods

class ServiceB(BaseService):
   some fields/methods
```

I have the same structure for service plans.

Here are my questions:
1. Is this correct
2. How can I access all the services a company has

Thank you

Comment: Are you planning to use BaseService or just Service A and Service B ?

Comment: Why don't you use [Model Relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/) . I think that's the best practice

Comment: I am planning to use Service A and Service B. The issue I am facing is when I query. How do I get all the services a company has.

Comment: Can you extend your question ? Provide code where you make relations between services and company

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
class BaseService(models.Model):
    common_field = ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ServiceA(BaseService):
    some fields/methods

class ServiceB(BaseService):
    some fields/methods
```

So basically your ServiceA and ServiceB will have common_field from BaseService automatically. And BaseService will not be stored in your DB

Comment: might be out of time, but have you ever heard of [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?